# How to change the data type (datetime) to (date) in the conditions of a running find?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I need get all posts from the current day (today), with the `find` below I'm not getting anything because the field `pub_date (datetime)` has time and the `new \Datetime()`  returns the current date and time so, the date will match but the time not.

```
    $posts = $this->find('all', [
        'fields' => [
            'Posts.id',
            'Posts.title',
            'Posts.body',
            'Posts.pub_date',
        ],
        'conditions' => [
            'Posts.is_active' => true,
            'Posts.pub_date' => new \Datetime()
        ],
    ]);
```

In short terms, I need get all posts with date equal "today" dont matter the time.

Comment: Sorry, what? `pub_date` is of what type exactly, `DATETIME` or `DATE`? And what do you mean by "_current date_"? The current _day_? And why would a `DateTime` object return `00:00:00` when it's not currently that exact time?

Comment: `pub_date` is datetime and I want change it to `date`.
"Current date" I meant "today".
And yes, you are right, `Datetime` will return the current time, but the current time is not the time of the `pub_date` as 00:00:00 is not anyway.